Mui styled components are not getting registered with React-hook-form
If i register username and password without mui styled components. it works
//This works fine
        <TextField
          id="username"
          type="text"
          autoComplete="off"
          inputProps={{ 'data-testid': 'username' }}
          label={t('COMMON.USERNAME')}
          helperText={errors.username && t('LOGIN_PAGE.THIS_FIELD_IS_REQUIRED')}
          sx={{ width: '100%' }}
          {...register('username', { required: true })}
          error={!!errors.username || isLoginError}
        />
        <TextField
          id="password"
          type="password"
          autoComplete="off"
          inputProps={{ 'data-testid': 'password' }}
          label={t('COMMON.PASSWORD')}
          helperText={errors.password && t('LOGIN_PAGE.THIS_FIELD_IS_REQUIRED')}
          sx={{ width: '100%' }}
          {...register('password', { required: true })}
          error={!!errors.password || isLoginError}
        />

If i try to create a mui styled component and pass props to it, this does not get registered with react-hook-form
//username component is not registered with react-hook-form

//create styled component out of react component like this
  const StyledTextField = styled((props: TextFieldProps) => (
    <TextField
      id="username"
      type="text"
      autoComplete="off"
      inputProps={{ 'data-testid': 'username' }}
      sx={{ width: '100%' }}
      {...props}
    />
  ))();


// using it like this,
        <StyledTextField
          label={t('COMMON.USERNAME')}
          helperText={errors.username && t('LOGIN_PAGE.THIS_FIELD_IS_REQUIRED')}
          {...register('username', { required: true })}
          error={!!errors.username || isLoginError}
        />
        <TextField
          id="password"
          type="password"
          autoComplete="off"
          inputProps={{ 'data-testid': 'password' }}
          label={t('COMMON.PASSWORD')}
          helperText={errors.password && t('LOGIN_PAGE.THIS_FIELD_IS_REQUIRED')}
          sx={{ width: '100%' }}
          {...register('password', { required: true })}
          error={!!errors.password || isLoginError}
        />


Not sure what is it that I am doing wrong here...

I think its because your styled component doesn't forward the ref, if you check the return value of the register function, you'll notice a ref to the input.
https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/register
register: (name: string, RegisterOptions?) => ({ onChange, onBlur, name, ref })

Either forward the ref in your styled component, or use the correct syntax for styled. If you're using Mui styled, the correct syntax should be like this:
const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)({
 //css here
});

